# How to calculate a continuous mean of a function

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I was just thinking about finding the continuous mean of a function $f(x)$.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_{-n}^{n}f(t)dt}{2n}$$
What is the right way to simplify the expression? How do I interpret the result? Does a "continuous mean" even make sense?

Comment: How do you know applying LR is allowed?

Comment: $f(n)-f(-n)$ need not be $2f(n)$

Comment: @Randall I see, I have made a mistake then.

Comment: I don't see how Leibniz Rule is applicable or necessary. You get $f(n)-f(-n)$ simply by the FTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to simplify the expression could be the following.
Supposing $x\in E$ you can define $f_n(x):=\dfrac{\chi_{[-n,n]}f(x)}{2n}$ in order to have
$$\dfrac{\int_{-n}^n f(t)dt}{2n}=\int_{-n}^n\dfrac{f(t)}{2n}dt=\int_E \dfrac{\chi_{[-n,n]}}{2n}f(t)dt=\int_Ef_n(t)dt.$$
At this point you could study $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E f_n$ usining MCT or DCT.